# Passing JSON data to javascript from python

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to pass some data retrieved from a database with python to javascript.

The code below works.   I can access the data in javascript but I can only pass one row at a time.

```
#!le/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import re
import datetime
import sqlite3
import json
import time
SQLDB = '/home/daylene/db/PiLN.sqlite3'
db = sqlite3.connect(SQLDB) 
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = '''SELECT segment, dt, set_temp, temp, pid_output
               FROM firing WHERE run_id=? ORDER BY dt;
          '''
p = ((54),)
cursor.execute(sql, p)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns,row)))
print(json.dumps(results[-1]))
```

And the working javascript

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showGraph();
        });


        function showGraph()
        {
            $.ajax({
              mimeType: 'application/json; charset=iso-8859-1',
              url:  'data.cgi',
              //data: JSON.stringify( query ),
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: 'json',
              method: 'POST',
              async: false,
              success:  function (response)
                {
                    //document.write(response);
 
                    var time = response["dt"];
                    var temp = response["temp"];
                    //document.write(response);
                    //for (var i in response) {
                     //   time.push(response.time);
                      //  temp.push(response.temp);
                    //}

                    var chartdata = {
                        labels: time,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'time',
                                backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                data: temp
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");

                    var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: chartdata
                    });
                }
            
            
        });
    }
        </script>
```

uncommentating `document.write(response);`
and changing to `print(json.dumps(results))`  does not work.   Nothing is returned with `document.write(response);`

Adding this does not work

```
for row in results:
    results1.append(json.dumps(row))
print(results1)
```

and then adding this also does not work

```
results1 = []
for row in results:
    results1.append(json.dumps(row))
print(json.dump(results1)
```

The output of `print(results)` (shortened)

```
[{"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 19:58:55", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145.02, "pid_output": 83.49}, {"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 19:59:24", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145.15, "pid_output": 80.76}, {"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 19:59:54", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145.16, "pid_output": 80.6}, {"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 20:00:24", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145.15, "pid_output": 80.73}, {"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 20:00:55", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145, "pid_output": 83.73}, {"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 20:01:24", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145.08, "pid_output": 82.1}, {"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 20:01:54", "set_temp": 1145, "temp": 1145.13, "pid_output": 80.99}]
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Your "output of print(results) (shortened)" looks like multiple rows. If you are confused because it all prints on one line in the console. try: `import pprint ; pprint(results)`

Comment: No I'm aware that it's more than one line.   I'd like to send the entire thing to JavaScript and be able to access  the data with response[x]["dt"]   where x if a row number.

Comment: You should be able to.  Why are you using `response["dt"];` instead of `response[x]["dt"] `?

Comment: That was an example of what was working.   I can get the results of one  line passed to javascript.    When trying pass the entire "results" variable,  document.write(response);   generates nothing in javascript.    So it's not getting passed correctly.   I just have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see how you are returning the json response.  You are only showing code that prints it in the console.  Try: `return json.dumps(results)`

Comment: I figured it out.   It's the size of the data I'm trying to pass not the code.   

Passing an object larger than 1 but smaller than the full one worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to serve data to your JS frontend from Python is by making a server that serves HTTP requests.

Using simple flask for example:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/my-data")
def get_data():

    my_data = [{"segment": 4, "dt": "2020-07-09 19:58:55"}, {}]

    return jsonify(my_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080, host="0.0.0.0")
```

And then you can request the data from `http://localhost:8080/my-data` in your Javascript.

Comment: This is part of a much larger project that already uses jinja2 templates and google charts.  I'm trying to move to chartjs for offline charts.   The chart will be inside a template and needs to be updated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Bleh, I figured it out.   It wasn't the code but rather the size of the data I was trying to pass.   Trying a smaller array worked fine.

I finally thought to check the lighttpd logs and I'm getting this.

`(mod_cgi.c.588) response headers too large for /app/data.cgi`